# Create a list of matrices based on several conditions

Tags: r, list, for-loop, matrix

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
cntry <-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
year<-c(1990,1990,1990,1990,1991,1991,1991,1991,1992,1992,1992,1992)
exist<-c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)
region<-c(1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1)

data<-data.frame(cntry,year,exist,region)
split.data<-split(data,data$year)

$`1990`
  cntry year exist region
1     1 1990     1      1
2     2 1990     1      2
3     3 1990     0      2
4     4 1990     0      1

$`1991`
  cntry year exist region
5     1 1991     1      1
6     2 1991     1      2
7     3 1991     1      2
8     4 1991     0      1

$`1992`
   cntry year exist region
9      1 1992     1      1
10     2 1992     1      2
11     3 1992     1      2
12     4 1992     1      1
```

cntry: country, year: year of the observation, exist: whether a country actually exists, region: in which region the country is located

For each year, I would like to create a matrix that indicates whether two countries, when they both exist, are located in the same region, and preferably store it in a list as well.

For the year 1991, the result would look like this (only country 2 and 3 do exist and are located in the same region):

```
b<-matrix(NA, nrow=length(unique(cntry)), ncol=length(unique(cntry)))
colnames(b)<-unique(cntry)
rownames(b)<-unique(cntry)

for(j in 1:length(split.data$`1991`$cntry)){
    for(i in 1:length(split.data$`1991`$cntry)){
      if(split.data$`1991`$region[i]==split.data$`1991`$region[j]&split.data$`1991`$exist[i]==1&split.data$`1991`$exist[j]==1){
        b[j,i] <- 1
    } else{
        b[j,i]<-0
      }
    }
  }
diag(b)<-0
```

The output for all years would need to look like this:

```
b
$`1990`
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0

$`1991`
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 1 0
3 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 0

$`1992`
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 0 1
2 0 0 1 0
3 0 1 0 0
4 1 0 0 0
```

I struggle to find a way to include the year dimension (also for storing the results) and am also wondering whether the for loop is actually an efficient way to approach the problem.

Any inputs are highly appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `tcrossprod`.  Loop through the list ("split.data") using `lapply`, subset the rows of the dataset where "exist" is equal to 1 (`x$exist==1`), select columns (`c('cntry', 'region')`) to create "x1".  Change the "cntry" column to factor and specify the levels to unique elements of "cntry" from the "data" (`factor(x$cntry, levels=lvls)`), get the `table` of "x1", `tcrossprod` the output, and change the diagonals to "0".  It is optional to remove the attributes of the result.

```
 lvls <- unique(data$cntry)

 lst <- lapply(split.data, function(x) {
            x1 <- x[x$exist==1, c('cntry', 'region')]
            x1$cntry <- factor(x1$cntry, levels=lvls)
            tbl <- table(x1)
            t1 <- tcrossprod(tbl)
            diag(t1) <- 0
            names(dimnames(t1))<- NULL
            t1
             })

 lst
 #$`1990`
 #  1 2 3 4
 #1 0 0 0 0
 #2 0 0 0 0
 #3 0 0 0 0
 #4 0 0 0 0

 #$`1991`
 #  1 2 3 4
 #1 0 0 0 0
 #2 0 0 1 0
 #3 0 1 0 0
 #4 0 0 0 0

 #$`1992`
 #  1 2 3 4
 #1 0 0 0 1
 #2 0 0 1 0
 #3 0 1 0 0
 #4 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility, the output is a list (with named elements per year) containing a list of data.frames with country in the same region, for each region:

```
res = lapply(split(data, year), function(u){
    df = subset(u, exist==1, select=c("cntry", "region"))
    Filter(function(x) nrow(x)>1, split(df, df$region))
}) 
Filter(function(x) length(x)>0, res)

#$`1991`
#$`1991`$`2`
#  cntry region
#6     2      2
#7     3      2


#$`1992`
#$`1992`$`1`
#   cntry region
#9      1      1
#12     4      1

#$`1992`$`2`
#   cntry region
#10     2      2
#11     3      2
```

So that:

```
#> res$'1991'
#$`2`
#  cntry region
#6     2      2
#7     3      2
```

Comment: Did you mean `split(df, df$region)`?

Comment: thanks a lot for the prompt reply @ColonelBeauvel!

However, the solution is not exactly what I've been looking for. The output for every year would need to be a matrix with the exact same dimensions as b and should indicate with a binary value whether two countries are located in the same region (when they exist), see the edited question above